# GoogleMaps API V3 Polygon dblclick auto-complete

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, polygon

I have created a plotting system using the GoogleMaps Javascript API V3, which allows users to draw out and save polygons.

I have received a number of complaints concerning the autocompletion of plots as a result of accidentally doubleclicking while manually drawing out the points using the polygon drawing tool. I am therefore looking to disable this dblclick auto-complete function, so that plots will only complete once the user clicks on the first point again.

I have tried unbinding the dblclick event from the map, and attempted to stop propagation of the dblclick event by throwing an error on double click, as below (just to test the event call).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(){
     throw("stop");
});
```

this succeeds in stopping the zoom function on doubleclick, but autocomplete still occurs when dblclicking while plotting points (this listener is not triggered). I have even tried stopping the propagation of any doubleclick event on the whole page, all to no avail. Can anyone suggest either a way of unbinding this dblclick event, or an alternative solution to prevent the dblclick autocomplete?

I have searched through the API reference document and forums and have not been able to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an edit button after finish!

Save your polygons into an array on "overlaycomplete" (and add your edit button at the same time)

```
var polyArray = [];

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    this.setDrawingMode(null);
    var shape   = e.overlay;
    shape.type  = e.type;

    polyArray.push(shape);

        shape.addListener('click', function(evt){
            if (evt.vertex != null && this.getPath().getLength() > 3) {
                this.getPath().removeAt(evt.vertex);
            }
        });
      });
```

The Edit function:

```
function editFeature(id, action){

    var shape = polyArray[id];

    if(action) shape.setEditable(true);
          else shape.setEditable(false);
}
```